# Why is it showing me like that in VScode for reactJS?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

[image]

Even though my project runs but I am having this warning here, In this Image, I am having the symbol 'M'. I don't know what it is please explain.

Comment: M is for "modified". You have made changes to these files. Nothing is wrong.

Comment: how should I remove this ?

Comment: Do you want to revert your changes, or commit them?

Comment: I want to commit

Comment: Assuming you're using a command line for git, you'll do `git add .`, then `git commit -m "some message describing the commit"`

Answer (score 2):

It's not a warning, it's simply a Git indication that the file has been modified from the previous commit. If you save all your open files and then make a new commit, it'll change to a green U (unmodified).

[image]

Comment: `U` is for untracked - not committed yet